# Travelling with a "Carta di Soggiorno di un familiare di un cittadino dell'Unione"

Tags: visas, eu, family, russian-citizens, hungary

so basically i'm a russian citizen who has been living (legally) in Italy for more than 10 years. At the moment of writing, i own a "Carta di soggiorno di un familiare di un cittadino dell'unione" which SHOULD be (since i don't really understand the burocratis around these kind of documents) the permit of stay because my sister was born here. On the document, there's no expiration date, it says "Illimitato" which means "unlimited". Now my question is, i would like to travel with my gf in Hungary for a week. She is italian, so she has no problems, but what about me? Do i need a visa? I've been searching for this topic on the internet for about a week but found literally a few posts and they do not solve my problem. Could you guys help me? Thanks in advantage and sorry for my bad english.

EDIT: if possible, could someone also explain me why can i or can't i travel, just to better understand the laws behind those replies you guys gave me since it's my first time traveling and i would like to be 100% sure. [image]

Comment: You don't need a visa. But you will need your passport in addition to the residence card.

Comment: @xngtng i do have a valid russian passport. Could you please explain me why tho? I mean i understand now that i can, but could you tell me whats the regulation behind it? Just to be 100% sure. This is my first time traveling outside italy (i came here when i was little so i dont coun that as traveling) so i'm a little bit scared about all the laws behind traveling. Thank you for your time

Comment: The passport is your travel document, the residence card only acts like a visa; only passports are internationally recognized and allow you to cross national borders (for a non-EU citizen in Schengen anyway).

Comment: All non-EU nationals wishing to visit or travel within the EU need a valid passport https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm

Comment: @Traveller okok that's more clear. And i can travel alone without the EU citizen that i'm ""linked"" to? Up to 90 days right? Thank you guys for helping me out, i really appreciate.

Comment: Yes, alone without the EU citizen. When travelling with the EU citizen, that time doesn't count towards the 90 days.